# Is HttpUtility.HtmlEncode safe?

Tags: asp.net, html, security, text, exploit

I want the user to enter text and i would like to show the text back to the user and keep all the whitespaces. I dont want any exploits and have the user inject html or javascript. Is HttpUtility.HtmlEncode safe enough to use? ATM it looks correct since its properly encoding `<` `>` and other test letters. To display the the text back correctly what do i use? right now i am using `<pre><code>`. It looks alright, is this the correct way to display it?

Comment: Is your intent to echo back source code, or just user-supplied text in general?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HtmlEncode should be secure as far as any HTML codes or JavaScript. Any HTML markup characters will be encoded so that they appear only as other characters when displayed on a web page.

Yes, if I wanted to keep formatting (including all spaces), I would use `<pre>`.

Comment: HtmlEncode is secure. It will replace < > & " ' with the corresponding HTML escape sequence (i.e. &lt; etc.), as well as replacing any multi byte characters with their numeric escaped representation (i.e. &#9786;)

Comment: It does not replace multi-byte characters from what I can see from looking at the source code.  Any character with an integer value ranging from 160 to 255 (inclusive) will be converted to a numeric escape sequence (i.e. &#255;); however, any character with a value larger than 255 or less than 160 (except for the five specifically mentioned characters < > & " ') is output as-is.  Why it even bothers to escape 160-255 is a mystery (e.g. 160 is in smack in the middle of the extended ASCII range), since those are not reserved characters in HTML text anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to have a look at the GetSafeHTMLFragment method in the AntiXSS section of the [Web Protection Library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/). This uses a whitelist of what HTML is considered 'safe' for XSS purposes, anything not in the whitelist is stripped out. [Blowdart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2525/blowdart) (who works on the WPL team) has a great [blogpost](http://idunno.org/archive/2009/09/20/antixss-gets-html-sanitation.aspx) on using the method.

Comment: +-0. Incorrect i am not trying to sanitizes html, just display the text again. So this answer is not right. But may be useful to others when reading